# SQL Join only on condition?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005

I have about 10 different sql statements that update different tables. They look similar to this:

```
Update Y 
SET x = n
Where something = @somevar
```

Now I need to Update only certain rows when the @hasRows var is set. I could simply do this:

```
if not @hasRows is null
begin
    Update Y     
    SET x = n
    from Y inner join #items on y.Item = #items.Item
    Where something = @somevar
end
else
begin
    Update Y 
    SET x = n
    Where something = @somevar
end
```

Is there a way to avoid the if/else and do the update in one statement?

I am using SQL2005.

Comment: How does n changes with join on #items?

Comment: @Nitin n doesnt change. The update only updates the items that match using the inner join. The goal is to update either all or or only that exists in #items and Y.

Comment: Anyway in whatever it is you are doing to have @items contain all of the rows if you want to update all of the rows? That would allow you to use the inner join update query no matter what.

Comment: When @Item is Null, then what will we have in #items? Idea is to put and or condition in Join condition, but for this to work, #Item should have 1 row even when @Items is Null

Comment: @nik Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are doing, but could you simply put every row in @items when you want to update every row? Otherwise, only put the rows you want to update. Then, you simply do the inner join update statement and it updates whatever is in @items (either everything or only the desired things).

Comment: @Nik for that I would need to truncate/insert my #items 10 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this: (copypasta your example)

```
UPDATE Y     
SET x = n
FROM Y 
WHERE something = @somevar
AND (
    (@Items IS NULL)
    OR (y.Item = @Item)
    )
```

The `JOIN` isn't used but it's always proceeding if `@items` is `NULL`, or using the intended condition.

Problem here is that your example seems to include a TVP `@ITEMS` but TVPs don't exist in SQLServer2k5? So whatever the value is should be placed in the parameter.

Alternatively, if #Table **exists** but has no rows you can do this:

```
UPDATE Y     
SET x = n
FROM Y 
JOIN #Items ON (@HasRows = 0) OR (#Items.Item = Y.Item)
WHERE something = @somevar
```

If you don't know whether or not `#Items IS NULL` then your condition is your option because declared variables are resolved before the statement is executed.

Comment: Lets say that I have a different variable to make sure that the #items table is filled with rows @HasRows - Now if @HasRows is true, then use the join, otherwise dont.

Comment: @vikasde That's not possible in SQLServer. You can't make a `JOIN` conditional in a single statement. You can only make the parameters of a `JOIN` conditional. So, you could `JOIN` to #items `ON @HasRows`

Comment: Thats it. Works. I tested it. Thanks.